# AJAX call works with GET but not with POST

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, .net-core, razor-pages

The following AJAX call is working for me.

**CSHTML**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '?handler=Delete',
    data: {
        id: $(this).data('id')
    },
});
```

**CS**

```
public void OnGetDelete(int id)
{
}
```

But if I change it as follows, I get a 400 error.

**CSHTML**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '?handler=Delete',
    data: {
        id: $(this).data('id')
    },
});
```

**CS**

```
public void OnPostDelete(int id)
{
}
```

[image]

Post makes more sense for me here. How would I make this a post?

Comment: Add an annotation above your action like [httppost]

Comment: You have the "[HttpPost]" attribute on top of your method in the CS file. Am I right?

Comment: Can you inspect your browser's dev tools and verify the `method` is post & the payload  & url are correct?

Comment: @DavidMcEleney: Added image of the error to my question.

Comment: @Benjamin: "'HttpPostAttribute' cannot be applied to Razor Page handler methods. Routes for Razor Pages must be declared using the @ page directive or using conventions."

Comment: @JonathanWood - that looks like you're looking for a URL parameter `id` - the id field you're sending to the url has the `id` field in the body. Change this to include the ID in the url, or try adding the `[FromBody]` attribute to the `int id` parameter

Comment: @DavidMcEleney: I understand, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the network tab in dev tools? With the full request / response?

Comment: @DavidMcEleney: It looks like Guilherme Martin may be on to the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor Pages are designed to be automatically protected from cross-site request forgery (CSRF/XSRF) attacks.

The request is failing because there is no AntiForgeryToken present on the page.

Solution:

**1) Try to add:**

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

in top of your .cshtml page. When you do this, razor pages will add a hidden input named __RequestVerificationToken including your request token.

**2) Change your ajax request and add this.**

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
},
```

**3) Configure anti forgery in your ConfigureServices method**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
}
```

After this, you'll no longer get 400 error.

Reference: https://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/

Comment: I was able to get rid of the 400 error by doing all three. Although I'm currently getting another error that I'm looking into.

Comment: I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` elsewhere in my page. (In Razor code.) But I can't understand why it's reloading my page.